# Java socket : how to prevent java.net.BindException

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I have implemented a LAN game and test on same computer by :  create a class, create a server and a client in different thread in this class and connect together.

After I close two windows (client and server) and I do above step again : run java class, create a server and a  client. I always meet this error : `java.net.BindException` (because this port has been created before and hasn't closed yet).

Every time I create server socket, in catch, I always put `serverSocket.close()`. but that error still met with me. Please give me some ideas to prevent this.

@ : and if we know one port has been created, can we close it, and make new ones ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything put in a catch block isn't run unless an Exception is caught.  Instead, put the `close()` call in a finally block to ensure it is always run.

Answer (score 2):

You should put serverSocket.close() in your finally block and maybe wait a few seconds before trying to bind to that address again.

Answer (score 0):

After calling `close()` on channel could be not enough. See explanation here: http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html
The TCP connection could stay in CLOSE-WAIT or TIME-WAIT state. 
You can play with reusing the address (SO_REUSEADDR), but it didn't work for me. 
The best is to wait exactly the timeout which is set for CLOSE-WAIT or TIME-WAIT on network level.